# Need to find unique values across multiple arrays (bi-dimensional matrix) but I cannot use VSTACK/HSTACK (nor VBA)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have three vertical arrays populated with data.

I mean that these arrays don't take a fixed range, they each come from a formula that spills data. This is crucial because I want my final list of unique values to be constantly up to date without me having to change the matrix it refers to, even as the length of each of those arrays (and thus of the height of the overall matrix) changes.

I need to find unique values that are unique across the whole matrix. Using UNIQUE in combination with VSTACK or HSTACK would make this super simple but I cannot use them (non-negotiable point).

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62204826/excel-unique-across-columns  There are some examples on how to do it with older versions.

Comment: here is another: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42582980/excel-generate-a-row-with-unique-data-from-multiple-columns

Answer (score 0):

If initial arrays contain small whole numbers (as in the example) you can use a formula:

```
=IFERROR(LET(data,($A$2#,$B$2#,$C$2#),m,MAX(data),AGGREGATE(15,6,SEQUENCE(m)/(FREQUENCY(data,SEQUENCE(m-1))>0),SEQUENCE(m))),"")
```

I hope you can use LET and SEQUENCE functions, if not they can be replaced by older versions.